# How to find sum of quadratic

Tags: quadratics

I got this quadratic function from physics that I need to find the sum of each term, up to whatever point. Written thusly:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{t}4.945n^2$$

And is there someway to quickly figure this out? Or links to tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the standard formula
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

It can be proved by a pretty routine induction.

Comment: and just times that by 4.945?

Comment: Yes, that's all that need to be done.